# Run javascript with different data depending on button click

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm sorry for not being able to maybe provide all info but i think this will be enough.
I have a external javascript file which i cannot edit, it calls an Iframe on my page and the data on this iframe depends on the data-profile-id="xx".

It is called like this:

```
<script src="link to external js file here" data-profile-id="xxx" defer></script>
```

The js file then locates this div `<div class="button-container"></div>` and shows a button on it.

My problem is i have 6 different data-profile-id's so lets say

001
002
003
004
005
006

and by running 001 i can't load the rest of them since it will only be checking the first one.

Somehow i'd want the button to hold the data-profile-id="xxx" and then pass the integer to the js file. is that possible?

for example:

```
<div class="agendo-button-container" data-profile-id="005"></div>
```

makes the script in head go:

```
<script src="link to external js file here" data-profile-id="005" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use Onclick https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp to pass data-profile-id into your script